# socat listen to all IPs assigned to a particular network interface

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, socat

Does anyone know how do I get `socat` to listen on all interfaces assigned to one particular network interface ? I'm not sure if it's even possible.

If I want to bind `socat` to a particular `IP:PORT` I always parse the IP info from the output of `ip` command and then bind `socat` to it like this:

```
NETIFC=$(ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)
socat -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:1234,fork,bind=$(NETIFC) UNIX-CLIENT:/tmp/foo.sock
```

I thought I would be able to achieve what I'm after by running the `socat` like this:

`socat -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:1234,fork,so-bindtodevice=eth0 UNIX-CLIENT:/tmp/foo.sock`

But I believe I'm missing some low level network programming knowledge and therefore don't quite get what is this option supposed to be doing and am just plainly hoping it should do what I want it to do, but in fact it actually binds to ALL network interfaces.

Comment: Does the physical interface (eth0) have multiple IP addresses or virtual interfaces (vlan, etc)? What are the destination IPs and Ports of the traffic you wish to listen to?

Comment: Try `range` option for TCP4-LISTEN.

Answer (score 1):

The following port forwarder listens on IP: `x.y.z.t:80`, without binding to `80` on any other exposed IPs (unlike the bind parameter).

```
SOCAT_SOCKADDR=x.y.z.t socat TCP-LISTEN:80,reuseaddr,fork,su=nobody TCP:a.b.c.d:80
```

If an interface has multiple IP’s, there is some experimenting to do! In the `ip v4, v6` case it might be best to use two forwarders. For my current purposes, the code above is sufficient.